# Chrome Custom Tabs, Hide Close Button and handle Device back button

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, chrome-custom-tabs

I am using chrome custom tabs in Xamarin android application and opening a google page url (it would be my website url in future), I want to know if it possible to hide the close button? currently if user closes the custom tab, a blank page is shown, I don't want user to close the tab.

[image]

Secondly if user presses the device back button, same thing happens, a blank page is shown.

What are the possible things I can do?

Answer (score 3):

In terms of the close button, no, you can not remove it. You can change it from an `X` to a back arrow, but that is it.

Chrome Custom Tabs is not designed to be used as an embedded browser, but as a way to open content that is external to yours, an Auth2 process, to show a link that is not within your domain, etc.. and thus keep the user within your app experience, once they are done with that external content, they return to your app via the close button or the soft/hard back button.

If you are looking for an embedded browser, Google/Chrome's dev team still recommend using a `WebView`.

> If you want the user to feel like Custom Tabs is a modal dialog, use the default “X” button. If you want the user to feel the Custom Tab is part of the application flow, use the back arrow.

re: https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs

Comment: My app was working fine in webview but google authentication has stopped working, I still want to use webview but is it possible to open custom tab just for google authentication and receive the call back and proceed further? any article explaning this flow will help me. I have to implement this flow in my website because website url is being loaded in webview. Do I need to add some condition that if website is being accessed in webview, then show google authentication in custom tab, otherwise just load in a normal browser?

Comment: @Ali You can open an Custom Tab for Google auth and upon login, you can capture the redirect and grab the auth token. You might want to look at Xamarin.Auth and use it as is, or just use it to understand the flow and redirect: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Auth#31-detectingfetchingintercepting-url-change-redirect_url

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using custom tabs you can use WebView to load your web pages. While you can't remove the 'X' arrow, you can create an activity with a WebView as its XML element and use the WebView to load your web pages.